# Reload a pivot jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, pivot, free-jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I have a pivot jqGrid I want to reload the pivot grid on a button click;button is not inside the grid;it is outside the div of the pivot grid.

I tried using :

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

but it's not working.I even tried :

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('clearGridData', true);
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' });
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

but it is just clearing a the grid and making it a blank grid.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Got resolution for my issue:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('clearGridData', true);
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{
datatype: 'json',
url: //Give your url
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```